# problems running PLSQL using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to run a PLSQL script which I have as a string value with the following method.

- I first create the procedure
- then I create a callStatement to call it
- and finally I add some parameters

I get the error message: 
    ORA-06575: Package or function PROCEDURE_NAME is in an invalid state

Any ideas what I can do about that?

This is the code:

```
public IResult createAndExecuteCallable(String queryText, String procedureName, Object[] parameter) {
    IResult result = new Result();
    String procedure = "create procedure "+procedureName+"("+queryText+")";
    Connection connection = this.getDatabaseConnection().getConnection();
    try {
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(procedure);
        CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("call "+procedureName+"()");
        commonPreparedStatment(statement,parameter);
        try {
            statement.executeUpdate();
        } catch(SQLException se){
            result = new Result(se);
        } finally {statement.close();}
    } catch(Exception e){
        result = new Result(e);
    } finally {
        closeConnection(connection);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Try to print out `procedure` string during your code execution - and then try that string using oracle client.. Is procedure created with oracle client? is it valid? Are there any errors?

Comment: "*ORA-06575: Package or function PROCEDURE_NAME is in an invalid state*" means your procedure wasn't created correctly. Did you receive a "procedure created with compilation warnings when you created it?

Comment: Additionally the CallableStatement with SQL92 [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16338_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleCallableStatement.html) should be enclosed in curly braces: `"{call proc (?,?)}"`

Comment: Recompile your Procedure!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments and some other help I found the solution. Here is the new middle part of the code, now including compilation:

```
        connection.setAutoCommit(true);
        PreparedStatement createStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryCreateText);
        PreparedStatement compileStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryCompileText);
        CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(queryCallText);
        commonPreparedStatment(statement, parameter);
        try {
            createStatement.executeUpdate();
            log.info("create ok");
        } catch (SQLException ignored) {
            log.info(ignored.getMessage());
        } finally {
            log.info(queryCompileText);
            createStatement.close();
        }
        try {
            compileStatement.executeUpdate();
            log.info("compile ok");
        } catch (SQLException ignoredToo) {
            log.info(ignoredToo.getMessage());
        } finally {
            compileStatement.close();
        }
        try {
            statement.executeUpdate();
            log.info("execute ok");
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            result = new Result(se);
        } finally {
            statement.close();
        }
```

One additional obstacle was the file content of the plsql code. It contained line breaks and Oracle did not accept them. So I had to remove them before creating the procedure in Oracle:

```
 queryCreateText = queryCreateText.replace("\r\n", " ");
```